Can I save this Aspen?
Due to a hand towel tied low down around my Aspen's trunk, its bark has rotted in a ring around the trunk. I removed the hand towel when I noticed that the leaves were dried out as if the tree were dead. As per this answer, I scraped some bark off above the rot and the tree is bright green underneath, which gives me hope.
Can I save this Aspen and if so, how? Is the rotted bark still functional or will it need a bark graft? I'm no good at gardening and looking for a relatively fool-proof approach if there is one.




Not an answer, but also bad news: that is “algae green”, not “healthy underneath green”.

@Stephie I think the picture is over-saturated - might that be the reason it looks "algae green"? It did look healthy to me when I peeled the bark.

Honestly, for an aspen, and not a very big one, judging by the picture; the "(almost) fool-proof approach is to plant a new one. They grow pretty fast.

Never heard of a "bark graft", and I would be surprised if such a thing exists (bark protects the treee, but as I understand it is dead).   If the green bit you show is healthy, your tree should survive - The green bit is called the cambrium and is the important part for a growing tree.
